# error in ngRoute when my link is not in the index page

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I refer to this project and its working fine but my problem is that, my links is not in the index page.
https://github.com/facultymatt/angular-unsavedChanges

I have two links for the index page: Setting & Account
here's my index.html:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="navCtrl">
    <div class="settingNav b col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-4">
        <a href="#/" ng-class="{a_h:isActive('/')}">Setting</a>
    </div>
    <div class="settingNav col-md-2 col-xs-4">
        <a href="#/account" ng-class="{a_h:isActive('/account')}">Account</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

my script inside index page:

```
var settingTab = angular.module('settingTab', ['ngRoute']);
             // configure our routes
            settingTab.config(function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider
                    // route for the account page
                    .when('/account', {
                        templateUrl : 'setting/angularjs/views/account.html',
                        controller: 'settingNavCtrl'
                    })
                // route for the setting page
                    .when('/', {
                        templateUrl : 'setting/angularjs/views/setting.html',
                        controller: 'settingNavCtrl'
                    })
});
```

my Controller:

```
    //for active nav
        settingTab.controller('settingNavCtrl', function($scope) {});
        settingTab.controller('navCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
            $scope.isActive = function(route) {
                return route === $location.path();
            }
        });
```

It is working fine, but I need to use ngRoute again in my link under Account, so I have 2 links in my Account, the admin & the user.
And when I put the same way like href="#/user" inside user.html & add the .when('/user',{.... inside the index page script, I got error. Why its not working outside the index page? please help me.

here's my account.html

```
        <div class=" accountNav col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-6" ng-click="myData.swapHere()" >
            <a   class="thumbnail setting_subcatalog_icon"  id="/user" href="#/user">
                <img class="img-responsive accountNavIcon1" ng-src="{{myData.images.current}}"  alt="">
                <p class="subcatalog_name">User<br>Settings</p> <!--  class="subcatalog_name_h" when hover    -->                 
            </a>         
        </div>

        <div class=" accountNav col-sm-2 col-xs-6" ng-click="myData1.swapHere()" ng-init="imgsrc1='setting/image/subcatalog_account_2.png'" ng-mouseover="imgsrc1='setting/image/subcatalog_account_2_h.png'" ng-mouseout="imgsrc1='setting/image/subcatalog_account_2.png'" >
            <a class="thumbnail setting_subcatalog_icon"  id="admin" href="/admin" ><!--ng-click="adminSetting1()"-->
                <img class="img-responsive accountNavIcon2" ng-src="{{myData1.images.current}}" alt="" >
                <p class="subcatalog_name">Administrator<br>Settings</p>                       
            </a>             
        </div>
```

I adder User and admin into my script:

```
.when('/user', {
        templateUrl : 'setting/angularjs/views/account_sub/userSetting.html',
        controller: 'acctCtrl'
        });
.when('/admin', {
        templateUrl : 'setting/angularjs/views/account_sub/adminSetting.html',
        controller: 'acctCtrl'
        });
```

And now my Tabs in index page is not working.

Comment: You've shown us code that works fine. And you've chosen to not show the code that doesn't work, nor the error you're getting. How could we help?

Comment: Im sorry I edited it already.

Comment: What is the error, and when does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying "href='#/users'", create a function that uses $location to set it to "/users" and call ng-click="redirect('/users'). It will handle the routes and will prevent the whole page from reloading, just the ng-view. Let me know if this doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys but I've already fix the problem, I just deleted my controller in my $routeProvider. thank you anyway :)